# Aida tutorial is unclear

Tags: web, pharo, aida

I am working on the Aida tutorial:

http://www.aidaweb.si/tutorial

but I got stuck on the end of the second section:

> In a workplace make an instance of `ADemoAddressBook` and fill it with
>   a few example `ADemoAddresses:`

Should I add an Instance variable?
I don't understand what to do in that if someone can be more clear and explain it to me? I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to create `Instance` variable (or better object), because this class probably doesn't exist.

---

By Wikipedia instance OF the class (not instance class) is:

> a specific realization of any object. Formally, "instance" is
>   synonymous with "object" as they are each a particular value
>   (realization), and these may be called an instance object;

To make that more clear, please take a look on this picture:

[image]

"Car" is class and "polo", "mini" and "beetle" are car-type objects = *so they are instances of class "car".*

---

Coming back to SmallTalk: How to create instance of one of the classes? That is simple.
You just need to use `new` or `basicNew` operator. More you can read there:

https://code.google.com/p/seaside/wiki/ObjectInitialization

http://esug.org/data/Articles/Columns/EwingPapers/class_initialize.pdf